# New PayPal Libraries

Tags: android, ios, paypal

Is the new PayPal Library which supersedes the older MPL capable of handling a subscription and a regular payment in the 1 checkout flow?

I couldn't find a clear cut answer after sifting through the PayPal documentation.

Comment: Are you looking for recurring subscriptions, or future payments?  The SDKs currently support future payments only, as seen in the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/).

Comment: Recurring subscriptions